# Estimating the total number of customers based on a subset of orders

Tags: estimation

Assume there are a number of customers, each of which has made one more orders. You now see a sample/subset of orders (lets say 1,000,000 out of 10,000,000) but do not know the total number of customers. How to estimate the total number of customers in the full dataset, based on the sample?

I can assume that the number of orders per customer follows a power law, but it would be better if I could do the estimate without this assumption, but base it purely on the sample.

Comment: So you get a (random?!) sample of orders and for each order in the sample you get to see, e.g., a customer id?

Comment: yes, you see the customer id in the order.

Answer (score 2):

If the customer id contains useful information (for example, they are numbered sequentially from a known starting point) then this becomes a variant of the [german tank problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) and could be solved by similar means, albeit with a complication that customers with multiple orders are more likely to be sampled (this may not make much difference, however).

If you cannot solve it that way, you have a tricky problem.  The number of orders per customer is probably meaningfully modelled as a mixture of poisson distributions, with unknown numbers of customers ordering in accordance with each distribution.  You could solve the problem by hypothesising a small number (one, two or three) of such poisson distributions and using numerical methods to determine the best set of values for their parameters and for the number of customers following each distribution ie the value of parameters most likely to have generated your finite sample of orders.

For example, if you hypothesis a mixture of two Poisson distributions you have a total of four parameters to estimate - the characteristic parameter for both the distributions, and the number of customers following each distribution.  If you evaluate the likelihood of your sample over the four dimensional space of possible parameter values you can choose the maximum likelihood combination of parameters as your estimate; then add together the two "number of customers" parameters to get your estimated total number of customers.